# Fetch data from sharepoint list and dynamically show in table

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am new into javascript and sharepoint.
Say, there are two lists, list1 (Process, ProcessImage), list2 (SubProcess, Process). In list2 "Process" is a lookup value from list1. The count of all three Process, SubProcess and ProcessImage is not fixed, so say n number.

Using JavaScript and HTML, I need to show the data on a Page like this:
**List1**

**Process**       **ProcessImage**
Process1        ProcessImage1
Process2        ProcessImage2
Process3        ProcessImage3
:   :
:   :
ProcessN        ProcessImageN

---

**List2**

**SubProcess    Process**
SubProcess1 Process2
SubProcess2 Process2
SubProcess3 Process1
SubProcess4 Process4
: :
SubProcessN Process3

---

Result in Tabular Form Using Javascript and HTML

ProcessImage1   ProcessImage2   ProcessImage3   ProcessImage4
SubProcess3     SubProcess1     SubProcess4
    SubProcess2

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SharePoint 2010 or above, you can use the JavaScript Object Model (JSOM) to access the list items programmatically, as in the following example code.

```
<style>
    /* Adjust this CSS as necessary to adjust the style of your table */
    #custom_output{display:table; }
    .column_outer{display:table-cell; font-weight:bold; min-width:100px;}
    .column_inner{font-weight:normal; margin:4px;}
</style>

<div id="custom_output"></div>

<script>
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var output = document.getElementById("custom_output");
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var lists = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); // blank query to get all items
    var parentListItems = lists.getByTitle("List1").getItems(query),
        childListItems = lists.getByTitle("List2").getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(parentListItems);
    clientContext.load(childListItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ // on success callback function
            var columnMap = createColumns(parentListItems);
            createAndAppendCells(childListItems, columnMap);
        },
        function(sender, args){ // on error callback function
            alert(args.get_message());
        }
    );
    // this function builds HTML columns and returns a handy reference map
    function createColumns(parentListItems){
        var parentEnumerator = parentListItems.getEnumerator(),
            columnMap = {};
        while(parentEnumerator.moveNext()){
            var item = parentEnumerator.get_current();
            columnMap[item.get_item("ID")] = createColumn(item);
        }
        return columnMap;
    }
    // this function adds a column to the HTML and returns a reference to a div inside it (so we can add cells later)
    function createColumn(item){ 
        var outer = document.createElement("div"), 
            inner = document.createElement("div"), 
            title = item.get_item("Process");
        outer.className = "column_outer";
        inner.className = "column_inner";                        
        output.appendChild(outer).appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        outer.appendChild(inner);
        return inner;
    }
    // this function creates a cell for each child list item and appends it to the appropriate column
    function createAndAppendCells(childListItems, columnMap){
        var childEnumerator = childListItems.getEnumerator();
        while(childEnumerator.moveNext()){
            item = childEnumerator.get_current();
            var lookup = item.get_item("Process");
            if(lookup){
                columnMap[lookup.get_lookupId()].appendChild(createCell(item));
            }
        }
    }
    // this function creates a cell with text derived from the given list item
    function createCell(item){
        var cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.innerHTML = item.get_item("SubProcess");
        return cell;
    }
},"sp.js");
</script>
```

How you would go about embedding that code on a page depends on the version of SharePoint you're using.

In SharePoint 2010, you can save your HTML/CSS/JavaScript as an HTML file in a document library, then embed it on a page using a Content Editor web part (editing its "Content Link" property to be the URL of the HTML file).

In SharePoint 2013+ you can also use a script editor web part. You can also use SharePoint Designer to create and edit a page to add JavaScript.